# Macro to paste only visible cells into email body not working

Tags: vba, email, excel

I am trying to get the below macro to paste in an outlook email body the visible cells from a sheet. The macro works great, the only problem is when people reply to the email, suddenly all the rows are now visible. It appears that when the initial email is sent, it must pasted the entire sheet but keep the formatting to hide the filtered rows, but when people go to reply, that all goes away. Any ideas?

```
Sub Send_Range_Or_Whole_Worksheet_with_MailEnvelope()
    'Working in Excel 2002-2013
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
    'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("APP").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'Remember the activesheet
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng
        ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
        .Parent.Select

        'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
        Set rng = ActiveCell

        'Select the range you want to mail
        .Select

        ' Create the mail and send it
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

        With .Parent.MailEnvelope
            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "Below are the accounts currently falling outside of our High Cash tolerance. Please let us know if any action is needed. Thanks."

            With .Item
                .To = "test@email.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "APP High Cash"
                .Send
            End With

        End With

        'select the original ActiveCell
        rng.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that happens. Copy the visible cells to a new sheet and the use that sheet to create the email. You can always close the workbook without saving once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I have used something similar to this to remove hidden rows in my sheets. This code will NOT work if ALL the rows are hidden.

```
Sub RemoveHiddenRows()
Dim count4, count6 As Double        

    While Range("A" & CStr(count4 + 1)) <> ""
        count4 = count4 + 1
    Wend

    count6 = 1
    While count6 < count4
        DoEvents
        Application.StatusBar = "Deleting hidden rows. " & count6 & " or " & " of "_
        & count4 & " done."
        If Range("A" & CStr(count6)).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            Range("A" & CStr(count6)).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            count6 = count6 + 1
        End If
    Wend
End With

End Sub
```